# Issue with DoubleClick method of Actions in Selenium WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

While working with selenium webdriver in C#, I am encountering an issue. Below is the code to click on the icon, which is marked in the red area(in the image).

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
IList<IWebElement> status = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@id='tblFileList']//tr//td[contains(text(),'New')]"));

for (int i = 0; i < status.Count; i++)
{
    action.DoubleClick(status[i]).Build().Perform();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    i++;
}
```

**Problem:**

The above code clicks on the icon, but it starts clicking on the icon from 0 index. Let's say, if the loop is running for 7th time then it will start clicking on the icon from 0 index to 6 index.

**Edit**: When loop is running, the click behavior is always starting from 0 index. Suppose, when the loop is running for the 7th time, then it should only hit the 7th row in the table but not all the icons starting from index 0. But, while using this piece of code my click event is triggered again and again starting from 0 index of the grid table and hence duplicate files are downloaded.

**What is the possible fix for this?**

[image]

Comment: do you not want it to click from 0th element. If it clicks from 0 to 6th position then it does click on all 7 elements. Also check if your status.count is returning you the exact number of rows with New status.

Comment: The above code clicks on the icon, but it starts clicking on the icon from 0 index. Let's say, if the loop is running for 7th time then it will start clicking on the icon from 0 index to 6 index. That is correct behavior. Still confuse what you would like to achieve?

Comment: @NitishKshirsagar kindly review my updated question, hopefully you will get my point this time.

Comment: @KunduK please review my updated question, let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @HarshSharma : Now I got your problem.Is that possible to share your url?

Comment: @KunduK - It will require authorization to access the link.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's clicking on the item at index zero is because that is where you're telling it to start.  If you want it to start on index 1, then you need to modify your loop like so, to have i initialized to 1.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= status.Count; i++)
{
    action.DoubleClick(status[i]).Build().Perform();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

That code will have it click through items at index 1-7.  Also, you don't need to increment i at the end of the loop.  i is being incremented in your for statement.

Comment: wouldn't this result in an out of range index?

Comment: Go through my question once again!